# specific heat in solids and liquids

Tags: thermodynamics

I read a text which said:
**specific heat of liquids and solids in constant pressure and constant volume does not differ a lot.**
can some one explain it more?

Comment: You should give a reference for this statement. Author, edition, page number.  The context of such a statement is important. Also, we need to know whether the comparison is between *all* specific heats, or between the $C_p$ and $C_V$ of a specific material.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a table of specific heats e.g. at

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Table_of_specific_heat_capacities

Look at the last column, for example. Almost all the specific heats are between $0.5 R$ and $4 R$, mostly around $2R$. This may be basically explained by each atom's or molecule's having something comparable to $2$-$3$ harmonic oscillators inside. Each of them contributes $R$ or so to the specific heat and the inner structure of the atom/molecule doesn't matter for the energetic considerations.

Comment: While true, this doesn't really get at the difference (if any) between $C_{V}$ and $C_{P}$.  This trips up folks because often those are introduced with ideal gases, and then they hit solids/liquids which (seem) to behave very differently.

Comment: I must have overlooked this essential part of the question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary material, $dU=C_vdT-PdV$.  If the material is incompressible, dV --> 0, so $C_v=\frac{dU}{dT}$.  We also know that $H=U+PV$ and $C_p=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$.  For an incompressible material, this gives $$C_p=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P=\frac{dU}{dT}+P\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}=\frac{dU}{dT}=C_v$$

Since liquids and solids are nearly incompressible, this is why their heat capacities at constant volume and at constant temperature are nearly the same.